# C# auto-increment operator error: Operand is not syntactically correct?

Tags: c#, operators

I'm looking at [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/increment-operator) and trying to understand how the operator actually works.

> The increment operator (++) increments its operand by 1. The increment operator can appear before or after its operand: `++variable` and `variable++`.
>
> The first form is a prefix increment operation. The result of the operation is the value of the operand after it has been incremented.
>
> The second form is a postfix increment operation. The result of the operation is the value of the operand before it has been incremented.

I would expect the following operation to return `3`, but it doesn't compile, and states the operator must be a variable, property or indexer:

```
int x = 0;
Console.WriteLine(x++ ++ ++);
/*Expected output: 3*/
```

Why is that wrong? Should I assume `x++`doesn't return a value of the same type for the next `++` operator?

Comment: It increments the variable and returns the result.  The result is a struct, not a variable. This isn't supported by the language.  Note, `0++` doesn't compile either.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the [draft C# 6 language specification](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/expressions#postfix-increment-and-decrement-operators):

> The operand of a postfix increment or decrement operation must be an expression classified as a variable, a property access, or an indexer access. The result of the operation is a value of the same type as the operand.

`x` is a variable, but `x++` is not a "variable, property access, or an indexer access."

Now, let's imagine a world where such postfix increment operator call would be legal. Given an `int x = 42;`, `x++` increments `x` to 43, but it evaluates to 42. If `x++ ++` was legal, it would apply to the `x++`, which isn't what you want (it would increment the temporary, not `x`)