# +intCounter generates Error CS0201 in visual studio

Tags: c#, loops, for-loop, compiler-errors

I am in a beginners programming class and have to debug some code.

I am unsure why this "+intCounter" is there, or at least why the IDE is showing an error.

```
for (int intCounter = 1; intCounter <= 100000; +intCounter)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C# auto-increment operator error: Operand is not syntactically correct?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48189588/c-sharp-auto-increment-operator-error-operand-is-not-syntactically-correct)

Comment: Your `+intCounter` expression uses the *unary plus* operator. It exists only for completeness. It does nothing but return the value it is associated with. What you are looking for is the *pre-increment* operator (`++intCounter`). It increments the value and returns the result (which means your counter will go 1, 2. 100k). https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/arithmetic-operators

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing you're trying to increment the `intCounter` in the loop. The increment operator is `++`, not `+`, which is the unary plus operator. I.e.:

```
for (int intCounter = 1; intCounter <= 100000; ++intCounter)
// Here ----------------------------------------^
```